# Conditional Rendering based on async function

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am playing around with conditional rendering in react but can't wrap my head around one usecase.

If I have an async function that checks if a user owns any number of a certain NFT:

```
  async function NFTCounter(){
    if (window.ethereum) {
      var web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum); 
      await window.ethereum.send('eth_requestAccounts');
      var accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts(); 
      account = accounts[0];   
      contract = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI, ADDRESS);
      contract.defaultAccount = account
      const Amount = await contract.methods.balanceOf(account).call()
      return Amount
    }
  }
```

Now I'd like to display a component if the amount is > 0 and if < 0 display a different component.

My misunderstanding here is not only how can I get this to work but the function will also need to be called/checked multiple times which could change the component I'd like to display.

I have played around with useState (example below) but can't wrap my head around how to get it to work for this scenario.

```
const [isToggled, setIsToggled] = useState(false);
return (
    {isToggled ? <Component /> : "Test"}

    <Button onClick={() => setIsToggled(!isToggled)}>Submit</Button>
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the more simplistic implementation:

```js
const [amount, setAmount] = useState(0);

async function NFTCounter(){
    if (window.ethereum) {
      var web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum); 
      await window.ethereum.send('eth_requestAccounts');
      var accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts(); 
      account = accounts[0];   
      contract = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI, ADDRESS);
      contract.defaultAccount = account
      const Amount = await contract.methods.balanceOf(account).call()
      setAmount(Amount)
    }
  }

return (
    <>
    {amount > 0 ? <Component1 /> : <Component2 />}
    <Button onClick={() => NFTCounter()}>Submit</Button>
    </>
)
```

But you can change behaviour according to your use case, like declaring `amount` as undefined and only ever rendering any of the two if the value is different than undefined(meaning the function has run at least once). Or even trigger your function on `useEffect`, to remove the need of a button.

> My misunderstanding here is not only how can I get this to work but the function will also need to be called/checked multiple times which could change the component I'd like to display.

In this case, you have a couple options, the more simple ones would be using `setInterval` if you want to run the function every given amount of time or`useEffect` to run the function when values of your component/app change